# How can I get one flex element to take the width of another?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Thank you again for your help with review my code and give some advice that I can use to move forward.

I am having trouble figuring out how to expand the services section below to inherit the hero section width. The image below display how the website looks right but the next image will show what the concept will look like.

[image: Example of the website]

[image: Design Concept]

**CSS CODE**

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-left: 1px solid #181024;
  border-right: 1px solid #181024;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #181024;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.site-nav-list {
  padding: 2em;
}

.site-nav-list li {
  padding-left: 65px;
}

.site-nav-list li a {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #181024;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 2em;
}

.button a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: 1%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-title {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.site-nav-list {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5.5vw;
}

button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero_services {
  display: flex;
}

.hero_lists {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.hero_lists>.hero_content {
  flex: 1 1 21%;
}

.hero_content {
  padding: 1.4em;
  font-size: 1vw;
  height: 20vh;
  border: 1px solid #181024;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.hero_top-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #181024;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 5.16em;
}

.hero_top-left {
  background-color: #E7DDF8;
  border-left: 1px solid #181024;
  height: 90vh;
}

.button_info {
  margin-top: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.button_info button {
  background-color: #181024;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.3em 3em;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.hero_email {
  background-color: #E7DDF8;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  padding: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <section>
    <div class="hero_top-right">
      <h1>Bring your minority B2B business ideas to life with our services.</h1>

      <div class="button_info">
        <a href="#">
          <button type="button" name="button">
                    Speak With A Perceptor
                </button>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
                Accelerate Program
              </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hero_top-left">
      <img src="{{ site.data.teams.team.ImgWorkHC }}" alt="Hunt For Careers Perview">
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<div class="hero_services">
  <div class="hero_lists">
    <div class="hero_content">
      <h3>test words</h3>
      <p>test words</p>
      <a href="">
        <p>Learn More</p>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hero_content">
      <h3>test words</h3>
      <p>test words</p>
      <a href="">
        <p>Learn More</p>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hero_content">
      <h3>test words</h3>
      <p>test words</p>
      <a href="">
        <p>Learn More</p>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hero_content">
      <h3>test words</h3>
      <p>test words</p>
      <a href="">
        <p>Learn More</p>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hero_content">
      <h3>test words</h3>
      <p>test words</p>
      <a href="">
        <p>Learn More</p>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hero_content">
      <h3>test words</h3>
      <p>test words</p>
      <a href="">
        <p>Learn More</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="hero_email">
    <form class="" action="" method="">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
      <button type="button" name="button">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, I have updated the code.

Comment: You need to start at the outside of your final image layout and work your way in. You have a row across the top (header), and a row below (page content). Inside the lower row there are two columns (white and purple). Inside the first column you have three rows (hero, two rows of blocks). Inside the second column you have two rows (purple, email form). Work from outside to inside, using flex rows and flex columns as needed.

Comment: My point is that it's not really about expanding anything. It's about getting the right layout to begin with. Your overall structure is wrong. Start fresh, one step at a time. [Here's your guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one example of how you could structure your HTML for using flexbox.

Note I have stuck with using flex rows as the default, but as @isherwood has mentioned in his comment above, you can also use flex columns or a combination of both. Either way will work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: #222;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 10%;
  padding: 0 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav__list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 50px;
}

.nav__item {
  list-style: none;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.flex__container-main {
  display: flex;
  height: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex__container-left {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
}

.flex__container-right {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

.top__container {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.bottom__container {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.top__aside {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 90%;
}

.bottom__aside {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10%;
}

.top__row {
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
}

.bottom__row {
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 33.33%;
  /* 
  4 cards per row would mean using
  width: 25%;
  */
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="nav">
        <!-- <img src="" alt=""> -->
        <span>LOGO HERE</span>
        <ul class="nav__list">
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="flex__container-main">
        <div class="flex__container-left">
          <div class="top__container">
            <h1>TOP LEFT</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom__container">
            <div class="top__row">
              <div class="card">
                <h2>CARD</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <h2>CARD</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <h2>CARD</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom__row">
              <div class="card">
                <h2>CARD</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <h2>CARD</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <h2>CARD</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex__container-right">
          <div class="top__aside">
            <h3>TOP ASIDE</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom__aside">
            <h3>BOTTOM ASIDE</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: for give some constructive criticism and give some advice for me to improve my coding and skills in flexbox.

Comment: Hi @BrandonPowell, you might also like to consider using CSS Grid for the overall layout instead of Flexbox as you have a 2D layout requirement for your task. You can then also use Flexbox for the 1D layout within each section, e.g. for the navigation bar Flexbox works nicely. Using Grid for the main layout and either Grid or Flexbox for the inner components will help to make your HTML structure cleaner and less nested. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your constructive criticism and give some ideas to look at in the future. I going look into this